# ActiveRecord firing 2 query for search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Here's what is happening with my application.

My model looks like this

```
class Model1 < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.foo(value)
        Model1.where(:field => value)
    end
end
```

and then i have a controller using this model

```
...
Model1.foo('foo)
...
```

Now, i am expecting it to trigger a single query to get the records. Instead of that, what i am getting is 2 queries.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `MODEL1` WHERE `MODEL1`.`field` = 'foo'
SELECT * FROM `MODEL1` WHERE `MODEL1`.`field` = 'foo'
```

Not able to understand why the first query is being fired and how to avoid it. Couldn't find anything on net.

Comment: Unless you are rendering the result of that statement, you shouldn't even be getting 1 query (due to the ActiveRelation lazy query trigger), let alone 2.  Can you show the entire code in the context this statement is being used?

Comment: `Model1.where(:field => 'foo')` by itself creates a `ActiveRecord::Relation`, but does not trigger any SQL request yet. How are you using the relation after ?

Comment: My Bad. Updated it. Hope i am clear this time.

Comment: Are you asking for `count` or `size` on any relations on Model1?

Comment: Not enough info, perhaps you are checking if it's blank somewhere? (or present, or any, etc.)

Comment: @Fred, not asking for count or size anywhere in the code. This is the only interaction with Model

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused (like others in the comments) but here's what you can try -

```
class Model1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.foo(value)
    Model1.where(:field => value)
  end
end
```

should be

```
class Model1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  def foo(value)
    self.where("field = ?", value) #see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#array-conditions
  end
end
```

Comment: Still got the same result. Anything i can help in clarifying more ?

Comment: sure could you paste the full output of the rails server for the action where this happening in the Question?